# Unable to get Expected output using spring-data Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**Problem**

I have to search user by name,contact whatever user types i.e if he types name he gets name only and if he type contact he gets contact only etc **instead I am getting all user results.**

**Solution -**

**1st Approach**

I have applied or query i.e findByNameOrContactOrLocation etc using spring data MongoDb.Below is my code.

```
public class Search {
private String searchKey;
private double[] location;
private List<Gender> gender;
private List<String> profession;
private List<INTERESTS> interests;
private int minAge;
private int maxAge;
private double[] height;



 @PutMapping(value = "/searchByEndUser")
ApiResponse<List<Employee>> searchEndUserBasedOnKeyWord(@RequestBody Search params) {
    return ApiResponse.success().object(employeeService.getByWord(params));
}


@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

@Override
public List<Employee> getByWord(Search params) {
    return employeeRepository.findByFirstNameOrContactOrLocationOrGenderInOrProfessionInOrInterestsInOrHeightOrAgeBetween(params.getSearchKey(), params.getSearchKey(), params.getLocation(), params.getGender(), params.getProfession(), params.getInterests(), params.getHeight(), params.getMinAge(), params.getMaxAge());
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {
List<Employee> findByFirstNameOrContactOrLocationOrGenderInOrProfessionInOrInterestsInOrHeightOrAgeBetween(String searchKey, String searchKey1, double[] location, List<Gender> gender, List<String> profession, List<INTERESTS> interests, double[] height, int minAge, int maxAge);
```

}

Input Supplied

```
{
"searchKey": "98111648642"
}
```

Output Expected

```
 {
  "createdBy": "anonymousUser",
  "lastModifiedBy": "anonymousUser",
  "version": 0,
  "createdAt": 1510303944245,
  "lastModifiedAt": 1510303944245,
  "imageIds": null,
  "concerns": null,
  "summary": null,
  "likings": null,
  "occupation": null,
  "religion": null,
  "education": null,
  "height": null,
  "location": null,
  "interests": null,
  "fcmId": null,
  "connections": null,
  "declined": null,
  "pending": null,
  "likes": 0,
  "dislikes": 0,
  "review": null,
  "ratings": null,
  "favourites": null,
  "disConnReason": null,
  "employee_status": null,
  "employee_role": null,
  "age": 0,
  "notification": false,
  "contact": "98111648642",
  "email": null,
  "address": "13",
  "gender": null,
  "imageId": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "middleName": null,
  "dob": null,
  "username": "jack",
  "country": null,
  "designation": null,
  "aboutMe": null,
  "profession": null,
  "sos": null,
  "secret": null,
  "socialProfile": null,
  "socialProfileLink": null,
  "socialToken": null,
  "socialProfilePicture": null,
  "referralCode": null,
  "refCons": 0,
  "referredUserId": null,
  "choice": null,
  "id": "5a0568c879eb192b872592b3"
 }
 ]
 }
```

**Below I am showing only 2 outputs**

**Output Shown**

```
{
  "createdBy": "anonymousUser",
  "lastModifiedBy": "anonymousUser",
  "version": 0,
  "createdAt": 1510228467303,
  "lastModifiedAt": 1510228467303,
  "imageIds": null,
  "concerns": null,
  "summary": null,
  "likings": null,
  "occupation": null,
  "religion": null,
  "education": null,
  "height": null,
  "location": null,
  "interests": null,
  "fcmId": null,
  "connections": null,
  "declined": null,
  "pending": null,
  "likes": 0,
  "dislikes": 0,
  "review": null,
  "ratings": null,
  "favourites": null,
  "disConnReason": null,
  "employee_status": null,
  "employee_role": null,
  "age": 0,
  "notification": false,
  "contact": "9811164864",
  "email": null,
  "address": "32",
  "gender": null,
  "imageId": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "middleName": null,
  "dob": null,
  "username": "jui",
  "country": null,
  "designation": null,
  "aboutMe": null,
  "profession": null,
  "sos": null,
  "secret": null,
  "socialProfile": null,
  "socialProfileLink": null,
  "socialToken": null,
  "socialProfilePicture": null,
  "referralCode": null,
  "refCons": 0,
  "referredUserId": null,
  "choice": null,
  "id": "5a0441f379eb1930d9f961b2"
},
{
  "createdBy": "anonymousUser",
  "lastModifiedBy": "anonymousUser",
  "version": 0,
  "createdAt": 1510303944245,
  "lastModifiedAt": 1510303944245,
  "imageIds": null,
  "concerns": null,
  "summary": null,
  "likings": null,
  "occupation": null,
  "religion": null,
  "education": null,
  "height": null,
  "location": null,
  "interests": null,
  "fcmId": null,
  "connections": null,
  "declined": null,
  "pending": null,
  "likes": 0,
  "dislikes": 0,
  "review": null,
  "ratings": null,
  "favourites": null,
  "disConnReason": null,
  "employee_status": null,
  "employee_role": null,
  "age": 0,
  "notification": false,
  "contact": "98111648642",
  "email": null,
  "address": "13",
  "gender": null,
  "imageId": null,
  "firstName": null,
  "lastName": null,
  "middleName": null,
  "dob": null,
  "username": "jack",
  "country": null,
  "designation": null,
  "aboutMe": null,
  "profession": null,
  "sos": null,
  "secret": null,
  "socialProfile": null,
  "socialProfileLink": null,
  "socialToken": null,
  "socialProfilePicture": null,
  "referralCode": null,
  "refCons": 0,
  "referredUserId": null,
  "choice": null,
  "id": "5a0568c879eb192b872592b3"
}
]
}

**2nd Approach**
```

1)I can check if the data is coming from user set it or set a random data.Though I have not implemented it.I am looking for alternate approach for this.

> Can anyone guide for what am I doing wrong or any alternate approach?

Comment: Surely there has to be a point where `findByWidgetOrSprocketOr....OrFifteenthFieldName()` becomes a clear "anti-pattern" as opposed to `searchFields() { return find({ "$or": [... ] }) }`. Just pseudo-coding of course but essentially writing a ridiculously long method name seems like sacrificing code clarity just for the sake of having something automatically scaffold a query condition which is really not hard to write. Such "convenience" methods were not really intended for this kind of abuse. You would IMHO be far better off understanding the underlying query DSL.

Comment: @NeilLunn Can you please specify clearly.

Answer (score 0):

findByFirstNameOrContactOrLocationOrGenderInOrProfessionInOrInterestsInOrHeightOrAgeBetween in your case effectively means

```
Get_me_documents_where {
    firstname : "98111648642"
      or
     contact : "98111648642"
      or
    location : null
      or 
    gender : null
      or
   ......
}
```

Since you are using OR,  it will fetch all the records. Because there might be some property which is null for all the records.
As @Niel suggested, it is not a good idea to have such a long query statement. spring-data-mongodb can handle this, but you will lose clarity.